# Bash RegEx Lookahead/Lookbehind CPU Information

Tags: regex, bash

I'm simply storing the output of cat `/proc/cpuinfo` into a variable within a bash script.

**/proc/cpuinfo:**

```
processor : 0 vendor_id : GenuineIntel cpu family : 6 model : 58 model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.80GHz stepping : 9 cpu MHz : 2562.759 cache size : 6144 KB fpu : yes fpu_exception : yes cpuid level : 5 wp : yes flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc up rep_good nopl pni monitor ssse3 lahf_lm bogomips : 5125.51 clflush size : 64 cache_alignment : 64 address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual power management:
```

When I cat the info to a text file and grep it:

```
grep -P '(?<=model name\s:\s)[\w ()-]*(?=CPU)' infotext.txt
```

I get a match:

```
model name  : **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M** CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

However upon testing this within my bash script I get no match:

```
regex='(?<=model name\s:\s).*(?=CPU)'

if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
     modelName=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Might this have something to do with the differences between cat-ing the output of /proc/cpuinfo into a text file versus simply storing it in a variable `cpuInfo=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo)` ?

If not, is the formatting of my regex within bash causing a problem? (I may need an alternate way of doing lookahead/lookbehind for 'model name : ' and 'CPU').

Comment: Did you try `if [[ $line =~ "(?<=model name\s:\s)[\w ()-]*(?=CPU)" ]]; then` instead? (Change single quote to double quote)

Comment: Bash regular expressions are used alone, not embraced within `'`s. Btw, I'm not sure if bash regex supports lookahead.

Comment: I have tried using double quotes, yes. Using the regex alone produces an error given the parenthesis in the regex. I can try and remove them  and match those differently. In most cases I use a variable regex='regexdata' and then run the comparison - which works.

Comment: Care: `cpuInfo=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo)` won't have same effect than `cpuInfo="$(cat /proc/cpuinfo)"` !!! (notice the **double** quotes)

Comment: @F.Hauri, I'm not using double quotes with the variable whatsoever. I was using quotes on the regex. I simply asked if the differences between the output to a file and a variable changed the way I could parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex don't work with quotes but it's possible to use a variable, also [\w] seems not to be supported modifying the regex gives the result:

```
re='model name\s:\s(.*?)CPU'
[[ $line =~ $re ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: I had already done a variable and modified my regex without '\w'. Interestingly enough even though that method doesn't use lookahead/lookbehind by normal standards, in grep it matches the model name and CPU in the string, but in bash it does not.

Comment: following my answer ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} will get all match but ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} will capture only first group between parentheses

Comment: That it will. That's why my question includes the question whether my understanding of regex within bash is off - which it is, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My purpose:

Care about the use of single or double quotes!

```
cp /proc/cpuinfo /dev/shm/infotext.txt

while read line ;do
    [ "$line" != "${line#model name}" ] && fld=${line#*: } &&
        modelName+=$'\n'${fld//CPU*}
  done </dev/shm/infotext.txt
```

Than:

```
echo "${modelName#$'\n'}"
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo 
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo
```

(there is two cores)

I don't use *overkill bash re*, because this way is a sensibly lighter.

But if you really wanna do this:

```
unset modelName
while read line ;do
    [[ "$line" =~ model.name[$'\t ']*:' '*(.*)CPU ]] &&
        modelName+=$'\n'${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  done </dev/shm/infotext.txt

echo "${modelName#$'\n'}"
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo 
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo
```

Well now:

```
unset line modelName
time for ((i=1000;i--;)) ;do
    while read line ;do
        [[ "$line" =~ model.name[$'\t ']*:' '*(.*)CPU ]] &&
            modelName+=$'\n'${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      done </dev/shm/infotext.txt
  done

real    0m2.001s
user    0m1.904s
sys     0m0.088s
```

2 seconds for 1000 x 1 test based on a bash regex

```
unset fld line modelName
time for ((i=1000;i--;)) ;do
    while read line ;do
        [ "$line" != "${line#model name}" ] && fld=${line#*: } &&
            modelName+=$'\n'${fld//CPU*};
      done </dev/shm/infotext.txt
  done

real    0m1.780s
user    0m1.716s
sys     0m0.060s
```

1.8 seconds for 1000 x 1 test + 2 string manipulation.

Comment: I like the way you did this answer. I am a bash fanatic and I recently began using regex in bash because it's quite powerful, yet tricky. Much appreciated, I'll consider this in future endeavors!